# Can Abel's Test be proved like an if an only if statement

Tags: calculus

Abel's test for $∑__$ to converge requires:

$∑_$ converges, $_$ is bounded and $_$ is monotone.

Does it work it work if I claim: $∑__$ converges if and only if, $∑_$ converges, $_$ is bounded, and also $_$ is monotone?

Comment: No? $a_n=\frac{1}{n^3},\, b_n=n$

Comment: No, this test is valid in only one direction.

Comment: @Peter:  Even with $a_n\geq 0$ it can fail in the other direction. Take $a_n:=b_n:=n^{-3/4}$

Comment: Also a counterexample : $a_n=1$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$